# What is a better way to write an if statement using PHP

Tags: php

I have a option dropdown where I need to echo `selected` if a value is equal to the search variable.

Right now I am using PHP if statements to decide this, but I would like clean it up a little by using a method that doesn't take up so many lines in my code.

Here is an example of my php if statement:

```
<option value="antiques" <?php if($_POST['category'] == 'antiques'){echo 'selected';}?>>Antiques</option>
```

While this works, it just takes up quite a bit of space in my code as I have close to 100 of these selection options.

Is there a better way to check if a post variable is equal to the value of this option and then echo `selected`?

Comment: Better way? inside that html, no. Shorter way, probably yes.

Comment: Quick thought: You could add all options to an array and then loop though it. Then you only got the line you mentioned one time in your code (if all options are belong to the same `<select>`.

Comment: What about using a templating engine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do this is using the PHP ternary operator (more info available here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php [scroll down below the big warning about floats])

```
<option value="antiques"<?php echo ($_POST['category'] == 'antiques')?' selected':'';}?>>Antiques</option>
```

It doesn't save much room in this instance, but it is a cleaner way to write it inline with HTML in my opinion.

Edit with code from @crazymoin

The idea of moving it into a function is great to make it easy too.

I would modify the function like this:

```
function abc($post,$value,$label){
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'"'.($_POST[$post] == $value)?' selected':''.'>'.$label.'</option>';
}
```

Then you can call it with this:

```
<?php abc('category','antiques','Antiques'); ?>
```

Note that if for some reason the specified index in the $_POST array doesn't exist, PHP will throw some warnings about an undefined index. You may want to expand the function to do some checking with isset(), etc. as well.

Comment: Trying this now, thanks @Justin Turner

Answer (score 1):

create a function and use it as many times you want:

```
function abc($postData, $thisData) { if($postData == $thisData) { echo ' selected';} }
```

Now do this:

```
<option value="antiques" <?php abc($_POST['category'], 'antiques'); ?> >Antiques</option>
```

hope it help!

---

**Change using Justin Turner response:**

Function is:

```
function abc($postData, $thisData) {
    echo '<option value="'.$thisData.'">'.($_POST['category'] == 'antiques')?' selected':''.$thisData.'</option>';
}
```

Now just use the function as many times you want:

```
<?php abc($_POST['category'], 'antiques'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like doing all my logic processing in one area of the code.

A clean way to do this would be to create an array with all the categories. Then fill in the one matching the category with selected. In each menu option, print out the contents of the array key matching the name of the option.

```
<?php
$selected=array(
                   'antiques'=>'',
                   'horses'=>'',
                   'umbrellas'=>''
                    );

$selected[$_POST['category']]='selected';

?>

<option value="antiques" <?php echo $selected['antiques'];?>>Antiques</option>
```

Comment: You could also use the category array to print it your menu, since the word antiques is repeated three times in the example.